# How Do I install an app on the ubuntu Touch device

Tags: mobile, ubuntu, touch, ubuntu-touch

I've been looking into Ubuntu Touch.

So I installed ubuntu on a Nexus 10 following the instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install)

I built the sample app following the instructions [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/)

So now I have a device running ubuntu touch and an application, how do I put the application on the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Qt Creator**: Connect your Ubuntu Touch Device through usb open your project and simply press `Ctrl+F12`.

This works only if you have once installed ssh-server on the device.

Alternatively you can do it **manually**. Copy the necessary files (*.qml and *.desktop) to the device and start the application via ssh

```
qmlscene --desktop_file_hint=/usr/share/applications/qmlscene.desktop YourApp.qml
```

[Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_SDK_Alpha)

Remember, this is all beta and if you are not a developer then you won't have much use for Ubuntu Touch at this stage.  Eventually, Ubuntu Touch will have its own app store where it will be much easier to download apps and install them on your device.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the sdk provided by Ubuntu, then all you have to do is go:

> Build -> Ubuntu Touch -> Install Application on Device

This will actually install the App instead of just running it. Now you can bring your prototypes with you =)